# USB Drive speed testing app with test options

Tags: usb, disk, benchmarks

I know there is a benchmark in the `Disk Utility` app, but I need something with a few more options. Some of my USB Drives are exhibiting weird results which may be due to testing patterns etc, so some test options would really help me out (chunk size, flush buffer on every write, test size, data pattern / access pattern)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iozone` (`sudo apt-get install iozone3`) gives you a stupid level of config and detail. There's also `bonnie++` but I think that has less use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal window then type in:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to get the name of the partition and next:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda1
```

Comment: obviously use only one sudo at a time :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [F3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/), from Michel Machado.